# numeric column names in R

Tags: r, numeric

I have a data frame as follows:

```
structure(list(`104` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "yes", NA, NA, NA, NA), `15` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, ">= 4.0", ">= 4.0", NA, "~ 2", "~ 2", "~ 2", "~ 2", 
"~ 2", "~ 2", "< 2.2", "~2.75", NA, "~2.75", "~2.75", "~2.75", 
"~2.75")), .Names = c("104", "15"), row.names = 45:64, class = "data.frame")
```

I know that it is not best practices to have numeric column names, however it is necessary in this circumstance. I have been manipulating my data frame through retrieving columns with a backtick `

Unfortunately, I found something funny in the above data frame.

```
> table(testtest$`10`)

 yes 
  1 
>
```

However there is no column with a name of 10, so it looks like it is retrieving

```
> table(testtest$`104`)

 yes 
 1 
>
```

I am nervous now, and do not trust that this may pop up again without my knowing for other columns such as `41` and `4100`.

Any explanation would be helpful! 
Thanks

Comment: It is better to use `[[` instead of `$` as there is partial matching

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is due to the partial matching.  To avoid it, use `[[` to extract the columns

```
testtest[["10"]]
#NULL
```

while the correct column name gives the output

```
 testtest[["104"]]
 #[1] NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA  
 #[12] NA    NA    NA    NA    "yes" NA    NA    NA    NA
```

According to `?"$"`

> Both [[ and $ select a single element of the list. The main difference
>   is that $ does not allow computed indices, whereas [[ does. x$name is
>   equivalent to x[["name", exact = FALSE]]. Also, the partial matching
>   behavior of [[ can be controlled using the exact argument.

---

In general, it is better not to have a numeric column name or names that start with numbers.  We can append with a non-numeric character "X" with the convenient function `make.names`

```
names(testtest) <- make.names(names(testtest))
names(testtest)
#[1] "X104" "X15"
```