# Write a function that returns a vector or list of three statistics

Tags: r, list, function, vector, mean

This is a question for school, but I have been working on it for hours and just need a point in the right direction. I am not asking for the full answer.

I was given a data frame with student grades for various assessments. I have to write a function that will result in a vector or list that will give the min, max, and average of one particular assessment.

I was provided with the following framework:

```
checkAssessment <- function(df, assessmentName)
{

}
```

I need to be able to write the code to get the exact results below when the following line of code is executed:

```
checkAssessment(df,"hw1")
# $min
# [1] 0
# 
# $max
# [1] 14
# 
# $avg
# [1] 12.58824
```

So, I have tried many ways to go about this, none of which have worked. The two that came closest were

```
checkAssessment <- function(df, assessmentName)
{
my_min <- df$assessmentName == min(assessmentName)
my_max <- df$assessmentName == max(assessmentName)
my_avg <- df$assessmentName == mean(assessmentName)
return(df[my_min, ])
return(df[my_max, ])
return(df[my_avg, ])
}
```

and

```
checkAssessment <- function(df, assessmentName)
{
my_min <- sapply(df$assessmentName, min)
my_max <- sapply(df$assessmentName, max)
my_avg <- sapply(mean.default(df$assessmentName, trim = 0, na.rm = FALSE,         
...))
funs = c(min, max, mean)
return(df[my_min, ])
return(df[my_max, ])
return(df[my_avg, ])
}
```

I'm not even sure if I'm close with either of these. I'm in an introductory R course so the code should be fairly simple, but I've developed a mental block with this question.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your were given the function framework, we have to use it.

```
checkAssessment <- function(df, assessmentName)
{
x <- df[[assessmentName]]  ## extract column vector
return(list(min = min(x), max = max(x), avg = mean(x)))  ## use a list for multiple return
}
```

Note:

1. to extract a column from a data frame by matching column name (exactly), use `[[]]`. It is OK to use `$`, but it does partial matching; Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39299697/4891738) can help you understand this concept;
2. be aware of R-base functions `min`, `max` and `mean`, so that you don't need to struggle with `x[x == min(x)]`, etc. Even if you want this logic, you can try `x[which.min(x)]`. Read `?which.min` for more;
3. If you want multiple returned values, use a "list" to collect all of them. The basic way to set up a list is like `list(1, 2)`, but a list can have names, so compare with `list(a = 1, b = 2)`.

**Test**

We use R's built-in dataset `trees` for a test.

```
checkAssessment(trees, "Height")
#$min
#[1] 63

#$max
#[1] 87

#$avg
#[1] 76
```

---

It might also be worth pointing out where your code is problematic:

```
checkAssessment <- function(df, assessmentName)
{
my_min <- df$assessmentName == min(assessmentName)
my_max <- df$assessmentName == max(assessmentName)
my_avg <- df$assessmentName == mean(assessmentName)
return(df[my_min, ])
return(df[my_max, ])
return(df[my_avg, ])
}
```

First, `min(assessmentName)` does not make sense. Maybe you want

```
df$assessmentName == min(df$assessmentName)
```

Then, `return(df[my_min, ])` is returning a data frame, a single row but multiple columns. Maybe you want:

```
return(df[my_min, assessmentName])
```

Finally, after the above `return`, the following won't have any effect:

```
return(df[my_max, assessmentName])
return(df[my_avg, assessmentName])
```

because the function terminates after seeing the first return. This is why you should use a "list" to get multiple returned values.